# Access UserDetails object in Websocket session Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

In a call sent over a websocket connection in a Spring MVC 4 application, I can get a `java.security.Principal` object when adding this as a parameter in the method.

However, this basicly only has the username in it, and I need the (extended) `UserDetails` object created during logging in.

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns `null`. As I understood because spring creates a special session for handling the websocket connections.

The Question: Is there a way to access the securitycontext from inside the websocket session/thread?

(Being able to access a session bean would suffice as well).

Comment: For others: I worked around this issue by using Spring Session. http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/. Didn't like this solution at all, since it requires me to keep a mapping between websocketsessions and httpsession. Feels ugly and insecure, but I had to get it working. Will keep this question open in order to receive more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@AuthenticationPrincipal` is specifically for REST/MVC methods.

However, you can get pretty close by adding an argument of Type `java.security.Principle` to your `@MessageMapping` annotated method and then taking the real `UserDetails` object from it as follows:

```
FooUserDetails currentUser = (FooUserDetails) ((Authentication) user).getPrincipal();
```

This works for me for Spring Boot 1.5.4

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have extended **AbstractWebSocketHandler**

the you could have principal name :

```
@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished ( WebSocketSession session ) throws Exception {
    logger.info ( "afterConnectionEstablished = " + session.getPrincipal () );
}
```

Comment: I need it in methods invoked by onMessage (with @MessageMapping).

Answer (score -2):

I've not tested it, but you should be able to access your user adding a parameter like

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser
```

to your @MessageMapping method.

You can find more here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal

Comment: Interesting annotation (didn't know of it's existence). Might work, however: I cannot test it atm to verify this.

Comment: `@AuthenticationPrincipal` only works for REST controller methods, not for websockets.  The link you refer to is specifically for mvc.